# Apache and passenger behave differently on Docker mac vs ubuntu

Tags: macos, apache, ubuntu, docker, passenger

I'm experiencing some issues with containers running apache2 + passenger phusion + rails app when I deploy them on mac or linux.
I use the same image (based on ubuntu:14.04) pulled from the docker hub and the same run command

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -e RAILS_ENV=development --link pg my-image-name
```

On OSX 10.10.5, running docker 1.9.1, build a34a1d5 everything works fine.
On my production server ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, running the same docker version, I get the following error

```
AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/app/app') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Permissions are set with chmod 775 -R /home/app.
Here is passenger and apache version + configuration

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Oct 14 2015 14:20:21
Phusion Passenger 5.0.22
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.my-app.com
    DocumentRoot /home/app/app/public
    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
    RailsEnv development
    ErrorLog "/home/app/app/log/apache_error_log"
    CustomLog "/home/app/app/log/apache_access_log" common
    <Directory /home/app/app/public>
       AllowOverride all
       Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
       Require all granted
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea why I'm getting two different behaviours between OS X and Ubuntu running the same container?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe switch to devicemapper as in https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16741#issuecomment-147332984?

Comment: It works great! Thank you! I thought that Ubuntu LTS would be using device mapper as default, but by typing `docker info | grep Storage` I get `Storage Driver: aufs` in both mac and Ubuntu. The weird part is that my image spin fine on mac with aufs and on Ubuntu on device mapper. Go figure! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented in [issue 16741](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16741#issuecomment-147332984):

> I think I've seen a similar issue, which was related to the aufs driver.
>
> Fixed by using "devicemapper" instead of "aufs" thanks to this post:
>   "[Switching Docker from aufs to devicemapper](http://muehe.org/posts/switching-docker-from-aufs-to-devicemapper/)"
>
> changed `/etc/default/docker` to enable device mapper:
>   (save the images first)

```
# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=devicemapper"
```

The [OP Alberto Sabaini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5634055/alberto-sabaini) confirms it works:

> I thought that Ubuntu LTS would be using device mapper as default, but by typing `docker info | grep Storage`, I get `Storage Driver: aufs` in both mac and Ubuntu.
>   The weird part is that my image spin fine on mac with aufs and on Ubuntu on device mapper.